# How to use a reference such that it results in compile time error or run time error?

Tags: c++, reference

I am unable to find a solution for the question one of my friend was asked in an interview... Below is the question:

> Define a class such that declaring/using a reference to its object will give
>   a. compile time error
>   b. run time error
>
> Generally, a reference would be of type `<class> &X = Y;`

How do we achieve the above and what happens internally when a reference is defined? Can someone please throw some light on that.

Comment: Is that the *exact* text of the question? If the question was carefully worded so that the intended solution would be a correct answer, rephrasing the question can mean it's no longer answerable.

Comment: My initial thoughts were we cannot just declare a reference . For example <class> &x; is just a declaration and C++ compiler doesn't allow that. However, It would help If i know internally what happens when a reference assignment is made so that operation could be made private and hence, reference assignment would fail.

Comment: this is the exact question interviewer had asked...N i am completely puzzled if there really is a solution that exists to this question...

Comment: Anyway, there is no operation that's performed (from the class's perspective, anyway) when you create a reference to an object. You could use things like `const Type t; Type& r = t;` to get a simple compile-time error, but I doubt that's the intended answer.

Comment: So it's a trick question. The correct answer is, "this question doesn't make sense".

Comment: Sometimes I expect from candidates also the answer "this is not possible"

Comment: @hvd : I have created my account today itself..Please give me some time before I get used to all these stuff...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Lol. What would you try if someone asked you this?

Comment: @user3086861 Yeah, I noticed that and deleted my comment, no harm intended or done :)

Comment: @jrok Well, unless it's a school exercise I would start by questioning the motives of this, and ask *why* anyone would want that. Then ask for more clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class whose instances cannot have references bound to them.

As for "using", that is too vague to answer.